# "Cannot find param" on defining function type returning a function in TypeScript

Tags: function, typescript, types

I have trouble with defining a function type that returns another function in TypeScript.

This works:

```
type HandleDoc = (doc: any) => any
type SyncHookDoc = (updateStore, doc: any, store) => (void | HandleDoc)
```

But if I try in 1 line it does not work:

```
type SyncHookDoc = (updateStore, doc: any, store) => (void | (doc: any) => any)
```

> Errors:
>
> Cannot find name 'doc'.
>
> 'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an extra set of `()` around the function signature:

```
type SyncHookDoc = (updateStore, doc: any, store) => (void | ((doc: any) => any))
```

Comment: Why is this so?

Comment: My guess is the the `|` has higher precedence to =>. so the compiler will see the type as ` (void | (doc: any)) => any)`